# Job Queues and Workers using Java, spring, redis

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, redis, laravel-queue

I want to create Jobs and Workers and process each Jobs created by REST request and also I want multi-level workers for single job.

**Scenario:** My Clients will post a request via REST API and the each REST requests are time consuming jobs

- Store that request into DB as a new job and store the ID into redis
- Define a worker which will pull out the IDs from redis
- Process the job and make that DB record as completed 
  Is there is any framework and technology or combination of technology that I can use to create my Jobs and workers on Spring MVC or JAX RS jersey.

I have done exactly same kind of project using PHP, Laravel Queue, Laravel Horizon and Redis but Now I need to develop using Java Tech Stack. It would be great if you tell me the whole stack for my requirement in Java.

Your suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is it continuously looking out for new jobs or is it scheduled? If scheduled, u can use spring batch. Else u can create it as a multi-threaded app i think!

Comment: Thanks for the response. Its not like batch. What I want is as soon as I get REST call I should be able to project that request as a Job. Publisher-Subscriber stack also work for me but I dont know how to select the tech stack using Java.

Comment: I am gonna try https://learnk8s.io/blog/scaling-spring-boot-microservices